# ListView и EditText в AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, listview, android-dialog

У меня есть AlertDialog, в котором я через метод setView() поставил layout(внутри него есть TextView и EditText),а также через метод setMultiChoiceItems разместил listView, но при запуске диалога сначала выводится listView а затем уже layout.А мне надо выводить сначала layout, а потом уже ListView

```
LayoutInflater factoryClient = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View view=factoryClient.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,null);

    question=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_question);
    ask=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edit_ask);
    question.setText(alarm_name);

    String[] plans_name=getPlansName(plans_list);
    final boolean[] mCheckPlan=getPlanDone(plans_list);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert_dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(alarm_time)
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_dialog_time)
            .setView(view)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(plans_name, mCheckPlan, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    mCheckPlan[which] = isChecked;
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false); //закрытие диалога через кнопку назад

    alert_dialog.setPositiveButton("Да", null);
    alert_dialog.setNegativeButton("Нет", null);
    alert_dialog.setNeutralButton("Отложить", null);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog=alert_dialog.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: это код на языке Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13859516/3212712), проблему можно решить установкой вашей разметки в качестве заголовка диалога (а не его содержимого (метод `setView`)) методом `setCustomTitle` примерно так:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert_dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle(alarm_time)
.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_dialog_time)
.setCustomTitle(view, null)
.setMultiChoiceItems(plans_name, mCheckPlan, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckPlan[which] = isChecked;
    }
})
.setCancelable(false); //закрытие диалога через кнопку назад
```

Чтобы при этом поле ввода текста реагировало на клик и запускало клаву надо проставить соответствующие флаги [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342347/alertdialog-with-edittext-as-custom-title-view/13411984#13411984):

```
AlertDialog alert_dialog = builder.show();
d.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
d.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет,вышло,но я теряю Title(setTitle()), можно ли как-то оставить и то, и то?

Comment: @Владимир, просто добавьте в разметку `dialog_layout` текстовое поле вверху и отобразите там заголовок)

Comment: Не сообразил.Спасибо,вышло))

Comment: @Владимир, если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, то вы можете проголосовать за него и отметить его "верным"

Comment: ЮрийСПб,я только сейчас заметил,что editText, размещенный в CustomTitle не открывает клавиатуру.В чем может быть причина?

Comment: @Владимир, попробуйте вот это [решение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13411984/3212712)

Comment: @Владимир, а вообще надо было б это отдельным вопросом задавать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35360/discussion-between--and-).